# Url.Action is not working with routes specified in controller using route annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-routing

I have an AdminController that looks like the following:

`AdminController [Route("admin")]`

`Index() (landing page for all administrative content)`

`UserIndex() - [Route("users")]`
`UserDetails() - [Route("users/details/{id}")]`

`RoleIndex() - [Route("roles")]`
`RoleDetails() - [Route("roles/details/{id}")]`

**These equal the following URL patterns:**

admin/users
admin/users/details/1

However, if I try to do the following in my view it does not work:

```
Url.Action("UserDetail", "Admin")
```

shouldn't this be smart enough to output: '/admin/users/details'?

It only works if I do `Url.Action("Index", "Admin")` since there is no route tag with it.

**Update:**

I am attempting to use [Kendo Template Syntax](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview#template-syntax) with a Kendo Grid ClientTemplate column:

```
    columns.Bound(c => c.Id).ClientTemplate(
        "<a href='" +
            Url.Action("UserDetails", "Admin") +
            "/#= Id #'" +
        ">Details</a>"
    );
```

**The link for each row ends up looking like the following:**
'localhost:9000/123'
The /admin/users/detail is completely being ignored...

And here is my exact declaration of the method I am trying to call in the AdminController:

```
// GET: Users/Details/5
[Route("users/details/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UserDetails(string id)
{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Recheck the routes and actions for controller

```
[Route("admin")]
public class AdminController : Controller {
    // GET admin
    [Route("")]
    public IActionResult Index() {...}

    //GET admin/users
    [Route("users")]
    public IActionResult UserIndex() {...}

    //GET admin/users/details/1
    [Route("users/details/{id}")]
    public IActionResult UserDetails(string id) {...}

    //GET admin/roles 
    [Route("roles")]
    public IActionResult RoleIndex() {...}

    //GET admin/roles/details/1
    [Route("roles/details/{id}")]
    public IActionResult RoleDetails(string id) {...} 

}
```

> shouldn't this be smart enough to output: '/admin/users/details'?

according to your routes setup `/admin/users/details` does not exist.

Its waiting for a request to `/admin/users/details/{id}` where {id} is a `userid`. So when `Url.Action("UserDetail", "Admin")` is requested, there is nothing to match.

```
Url.Action("UserDetail", "Admin", new { id = "1" })
```

You can make the `id` parameter optional by updating the route

```
[Route("users/details/{id?}")]
```

This will allow `users/details` to work. but the value of `id` parameter will default to `null`.

> It only works if I do `Url.Action("Index", "Admin")` since there is no route tag with it

It only works with `Url.Action("Index", "Admin")` because convention matches Index by default.

Comment: hmm I believe your on to something here. Can you please see the update at the bottom of my post?

Comment: Just know that #= Id # is a placeholder for the Id of the row in the grid. I just figured out what my problem was based on your answer. Let me know if you can tell me why. This works: Url.Action("UserDetails", "Admin", new { id = "#= Id #"}) + "'" +">Details</a>" and THIS DOES NOT: Url.Action("UserDetails", "Admin") + "/#= Id #'"

Comment: The first one `Url.Action("UserDetails", "Admin", new { id = "#= Id #"})` matches the route template for `users/details/{id}` because yo included the string `id` parameter while no match was found for the second one.

Comment: Got ya, so the second example would only work if the route was declared as [[Route("users/details")] and the function accepts a param of id. Is this correct?

Comment: The second one could work if you omit `id` [Route("users/details")] or make the `id` optional. `[Route("users/details/{id?}")]` the way you had it indicated that `id` was **mandatory**